# Missing dll error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

In my references, I have Newtonsoft.Json added. After syncing the project, I get this :
[image]

I deleted and added again the dll, but it didn't work. Can you tell me what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding through Package Manager

Comment: just ignore red line and build it, it'll download packcage and install by itself.

Answer (score 0):

First download the Newtonsoft.json from the Nuget package manager.
Now clean and rebuild the whole project solution.Later add the dll as references to your project through add reference option.
If this doesn't work make sure to make the copy of dll local.
[image]